# joomla 3.1.5 getForm

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I develop a component that use a form submission in both front-end and back-end.

I use `getForm` like `weblink` component.

Now, `getForm()` works in Back-end but in front-end not work, It generate error message about `Jform`.

I can not know the `weblink` component in view and model(`form`) and what it has done to show form.

```
require_once JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.'/models/shop.php';
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/tables');

class componentNameModelShopForm extends componentNameModelShop
{

    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
        {
            $form = $this->loadForm('com_componentName.shop', 'shop', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
            if (empty($form))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return $form;
        }
}
```

This class also has `getItem()` and `loadFormData()` method.

`$form` in back-end work good but in front-end always be false;

in front-end i `extends` this model class and before the class declaration i `include_once` it.

Comment: What error message does it generate? Where is your code? Provide more information in your question. You should also upgrade to Joomla 3.2 as it's the latest stable release of the 3.x series.

Comment: joomla 3.2 has very little component, also old component in joomla 3.2 work partial.

Comment: As mentioned before, what error message are you getting?

Comment: Which model class are you extending in your model, which is getting form?

Comment: JForm::getInstance could not load file

Answer (score 0):

By adding this two line before `$this->ladForm()` it works good, without including `JTable`.

```
JForm::addFormPath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/models/forms');
JForm::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/models/fields');
```